# Максимальное и минимальное значение по столбцу Laravel

Tags: laravel, max, min

В блэйде получаю массив $products, подскажите пожалуйста как получить максимальное и минимальное значение по столбцу price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неужели так сложно уже посмотреть в документацию?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-max
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-min

другими словами, если даже это прочитать и найти решение не удалось:

`$products->max('price')` и 
`$products->min('price')`